# is there a command in postgres SQL that is like the "NOT" command?

Tags: sql, command

For example:

```
Apple is a and b
Banana is a and b
Orange is a
```

I'm trying to write a command where it will only show things with a only and not b.

Comment: What do you mean exaclty? Perhaps you want to use the `LIKE` operator: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table structure

```
Fruit | Attribute
Apple   A
Apple   B
Banana  A
Banana  B
Orange  A
```

The query

```
select t1.* from tbl t1
where t1.attribute = 'A'
and not exists (select * from tbl t2
                where t2.fruit=t1.fruit and t2.attribute <> 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just the 'sql' tag right now, so this is Standard SQL-2003:

```
WITH tbl (Fruit, Attribute)
     AS
     (
      SELECT Fruit, Attribute
        FROM (
              VALUES ('Apple', 'A'), 
                     ('Apple', 'B'), 
                     ('Banana', 'A'), 
                     ('Banana', 'B'), 
                     ('Orange', 'A')
             ) AS tbl (Fruit, Attribute)
     )
SELECT T1.Fruit, T1.Attribute
  FROM tbl AS T1
 WHERE T1.Attribute = 'A'
       AND 1 = (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM tbl AS T2
                 WHERE T2.Fruit = T1.Fruit
               );
```